# How to access containing QML StackView?

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to QML, I have a Component which is pushed on a StackView. I'd like from this component to access the StackView containing it.

Here is a code that works

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls.2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        initialItem: test1
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Component {
        id: test1
        Button {
            text: "Go to test2"
            onClicked: stackView.push(test2)
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: test2
        Button {
            text: "Back to test1"
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd like to avoid accessing `stackView` by its `id`

[`Stack.view`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html#supported-attached-properties) seems to be what I'm looking for, but I have no idea how to use it. I tried all of the following (replacing `Button`s' `onClicked`) :

```
Stack.view.push(test2)
view.push(test2)
test1.Stack.view.push(test2)
test1.view.push(test2)
```

None of these work.
Am I misunderstanding something ? How am I supposed to use `Stack.view` ?

Edit : this question looks really close to mine : [Access QML StackView from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652163/access-qml-stackview-from-a-control)

I could indeed use a property to keep a reference to my `StackView`, but I would still like to avoid that if possible.
The accepted answer says that `root.StackView.view.pop()` is the correct method. I assume `root` is the `Page`'s `id` from this post, so I tried `test1.StackView.view.push(test2)`, but this still doesn't work. (Also tried with `root`, but it's not better)

Comment: did you also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652163/access-qml-stackview-from-a-control  . The first answer seems to be what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access QML StackView from a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652163/access-qml-stackview-from-a-control)

Comment: @eyllanesc Possible indeed... I didn't see that. Edit (actually delete and repost, the edit button disappeared) : comment added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Be aware that this Q/A is about the QtQuick.Controls 2.x

I also think it is good style to first use the attached property, rather than doubling this functionality by adding own, custom properties.

The problem is, that you are using the attached property in the wrong place - it is attached to the `Item` that is pushed onto the `StackView` and not to any of its children. So to use the attached property, you need to specify an identifier of this Item first.

In the example, that has been linked, this is `root`. But it is not the `id` of the `Component`-object. It has to be the root-node of the content of the `Component`-object.

You should have something like this:

```
Component {
    id: myComponent
    Item { // The Page. To this the attached property will be attached.
        id: myComponentRoot // Use this to identify the root node of the pushed item.
        Item { // Some more layers ...
        ...
            Button { // Here you now want to access it perhaps?
                onClicked: myComponentRoot.StackView.view.pop() // Reference the root node of the component to access it's attached properties.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `myComponentRoot.StackView.view` is undefined

Comment: In which case, please share a minimal complete and verifiable example.

Comment: In your question you use the deprecated QtQuick.Controls 1. This question is about the modern version 2.x

Comment: I will have a look once I am back to civilization.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of convenient using `StackView.view` is by assigning it to a property. In the following, I deliberately did not give the parent `StackView` an `id`. I can create a property in the sub-pages to grant access to the `StackView` as follows:

```
    property StackView stackView: StackView.view
```

Here's a fully working example:

```
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    StackView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "Test1.qml"
    }
}

//Test1.qml
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    property StackView stackView: StackView.view
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Go to test2"
        onClicked: stackView.push("Test2.qml")
    }
}

//Test2.qml
import QtQuick 
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    property StackView stackView: StackView.view
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Back to test1"
        onClicked: stackView.pop()
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACWnic1Y87D8IgEIB3fgXpVBdMO3bUwXSz0biTeiop5RCuPmL872Kjra9EVy+EcA/g+1Rt0REvqGhUWXGmnnIxRkMOtWdsKtfAT4yHmJEsq4WC/S2/hjTlBp0XK6V1xq10YKhrKqNISZ0T1BmP5uApEdtaR+3AmZ0ZGw676gvCb0jWoQVHxwc2fz9lfVHswtZeGDVEaD4IlAEcXG7eJAgOFOgnyCmsQJtGXQ/NWAc2WGb9t8I2fhO3tmlrO3jVTf9AdxSeugsn34TRxr3kBVZKvB4=)

Comment: This one worked the best for me.